# Why is try catch sometimes ignored?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception, visual-studio-debugging

One example is this code:

```
try
{
    string domain = o.SelectToken("response[" + i + "].domain").ToString();
    ...
}
catch(Exception)
{
    continue;
}
```

Instead of just going on in the loop("continue"), vs halts and points at `string domain = o.SelectToken("response[" + i + "].domain").ToString();` for an `System.IndexOutOfRangeException`.

Why is that?

Comment: If you mean during debugging that's a setting that allows VS to stop on exceptions when they show up.

Comment: What loop are you referring to?

Comment: @ScottHunter An intelligent programmer knows that continue in a try catch only makes sense in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using two ways.

1. As suggested in MSDN, is to set it up in your Visual Studio (I believe it's 2019)

   <kbd>Debug</kbd> > <kbd>Windows</kbd> > <kbd>Exception Settings</kbd>: Search for *index* and untick.
2. Please add exception to handle exception in your code..

   ```cs
   catch(IndexOutOfRangeException e)
   {
   // handle it like logging it in file and continue
       continue;
   }
   catch(Exception)
   {
       continue;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 7):

You probably have 'break on all exceptions' selected in the Debug>Windows>Exception settings:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2019

Unselecting this will let VS proceed.